# " with tipa and babel's ngerman / \shorthandoff{"} in a macro

Tags: macros, babel, incompatibility, shorthands, tipa

---

*TL;DR see below at "core problem"*

---

### Problem

I'm trying to solve a conflict between the packages `tipa` (*Fonts and macros for IPA phonetics characters*) and `babel` with the `ngerman` option. The problem is the `"` character, which both packages make use of. I've gotten pretty far, here's what I've got:

#### Using just `tipa`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \textipa{" ""}
\end{document}
```

produces the desired

> ˈ ˌ

(primary and secondary stress)

#### Using just `babel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  "a "s "‘ "’ "< ">
\end{document}
```

produces the desired

> ä ß „ “ « »

(result of `babel` shorthands specific to `ngerman`, i.e. `english` wouldn't produce this output)

#### Using `babel` and `tipa`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \textipa{"x""x"a"s}
\end{document}
```

produces the not desired

> ˈxxäß

Problem: the secondary stress is broken and a primary stress (`"`) a) before a vowel results in a diaeresis or trema (= two dots, "umlaut") on the vowel and b) before an `s` results in a sharp s (ß).

### My approach

Since in `\textipa`, `"` should be picked up by `tipa`, I used `babel`'s `\shorthandoff{"}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \shorthandoff{"}
  \textipa{"a""s}
\end{document}
```

produces the desired

> ˈxˌxˈaˈs

Problem solved? Not quite. To limit the scope of `\shorthandoff{"}` and to save typing, I put it in a macro `\myipa`, which doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\myipa}[1]{\shorthandoff{"}\textipa{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \myipa{"x""x"a"s}
\end{document}
```

produces the not desired

> ˈxxäß

Putting the `\shorthandoff{"}` in `\textipa`'s argument doesn't make a difference (`\newcommand{\myipa}[1]{\textipa{\shorthandoff{"}#1}}`).

Generally, putting `\shorthandoff{"}` in a macro works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\shoff}{{\shorthandoff{"} "a}}
\begin{document}
  "a \shoff{} "a
\end{document}
```

produces the desired

> ä "a ä

---

## TL;DR – the core problem

`babel`'s `\shorthandoff{"}` doesn't seem to have an effect on input characters called outside of its direct range:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\shoff}[1]{{\shorthandoff{"} 2"a #1}}
\begin{document}
  1"a \shoff{3"a} 4"a
\end{document}
```

produces

> 1ä 2"a 3ä 4ä

i.e. `"a` called in the same macro as `\shorthandoff{"}` produces **"a** (2), but `"a` called as an argument to a macro containing `\shorthandoff{"}` procudes **ä** (3).

**How can I fix this macro to succeed in this last step of getting `tipa` and `babel`/`ngerman` to be friends?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's "TL;DR"?

Comment: It stands for "too long, didn't read", the comma probably has turned into a semicolon because it's all-caps? I think it started out as a comment to posts perceived as too long, and has since become kind of a synonym for "summary" or "short version", for those people who don't want to read the whole thing and would otherwise add "TL;DR" as a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to defer gathering the argument:

```
\newcommand{\myipa}{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}\myipaI}
\newcommand{\myipaI}[1]{\tipaencoding #1\endgroup}
```

This will typeset correctly the bit `\myipa{"x""x"a"s}`. Of course such a command can't go in the argument of other commands. Should you need it into a section title, say

```
\shorthandoff{"}
\section{\textipa{"x""x"a"s}}
\shorthandon{"}
```

Here `\myipa` would not work if you need to typeset the table of contents. It's always the same problem: when some characters are gathered as arguments, their category code is fixed.

This however suggests a different approach:

```
\newcommand{\myipa}[1]{{\shorthandoff{"}\scantokens{\tipaencoding#1\endinput}}}
```

Or `\DeclareRobustCommand`, if you need it frequently in moving arguments; it's always possible to precede `\myipa` with `\protect`, for one or two cases.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\myipa}[1]{{\shorthandoff{"}\scantokens{\tipaencoding#1\endinput}}}` works in all cases, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `babel`'s `spanish` option. A simple workaround is to instruct `babel` to load two languages and set the language to `english` whenever IPA is called for:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % or [spanish,english], or whatever
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand{\myipa}[1]{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\textipa{#1}\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
% ... stuff in German ...
\myipa{"x""x"a"s} % should be 'x,x'a's
% ... more stuff in German ...
\end{document}
```

This approach should also take care of other potential clashes not to do with the `"` character.