# babel shorthand "| doesn't work in macros

Tags: macros, babel, ligatures, shorthands

The package `babel` with the `ngerman` option (and most other languages as well, but not `english`) provides the shorthand `"|`, which prevents a ligature at the given position (see p. 81 of the [`babel` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/babel/babel.pdf), e.g. `Auf"|lage` will result in the word *Auflage* without an fl-ligature (as is desired because, in German, you don't want ligatures across morpheme borders).

However, when placed in a macro, `"|` doesn't work anymore. Why is this and how can I circumvent it?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% doesn't help
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand{\foo}{"|}

\begin{document}

ff

f"|f

f\foo f

\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

Comment: Let me note for searchability that this is also the case with environment definitions.

Comment: Note that context-sensitive ligature suppression is implemented by the [selnolig package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works if you switch the shorthand on before defining the command, or if you define the command after `\begin{document}` when shorthands are active.

As Joseph commented, it's recommendable to switch it off immediately afterwards, so that the active shorthand doesn't affect other commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\shorthandon{"}
\newcommand{\foo}{"|}
\shorthandoff{"}
\begin{document}
ff

f"|f

f\foo f
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Alternatively, you could switch it on locally within the macro definition, similar as written [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29978/with-tipa-and-babels-ngerman-shorthandoff-in-a-macro) by egreg, and made robust, so it can be used within moving arguments, such as `\chapter` and `\section` headings and captions.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{\shorthandon{"}\scantokens{"|\endinput}}
```

However, it might be useful to have a part in the preamble where shorthands are active, as in the first solution, so you can use them in your commands such as in text arguments to macros.

Comment: I'd also switch the shorthand off after the definition, as other parts of the preamble might otherwise be affected.

Comment: You should also switch it off using `\shorthandoff{"}` after the definition. Otherwise you may run into catcode problems at the preamble (e.g. loading other packages after the definition). That's the reason for babel does not active the shorthands while loading the language file but just after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Are those shorthands based on "real" latex commands? If so, what are they? I just need to use `"-` once in the preamble, so just using `\whatever` would be shorter than turning shorthands on and off…