# Using "German" quotation marks inside \newcommand

Tags: macros, punctuation, expansion, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [babel shorthand "| doesn’t work in macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/babel-shorthand-doesnt-work-in-macros)

I know there is a deeper non-understanding of LaTeX mechanics at work here, but I have no idea how to phrase my question to cover the general case, sorry.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Trivial case, the "real" macro is a *bit* more involved
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{"`#1"'}

\begin{document}

"`Foo"'
\mymacro{Bar}

\end{document}
```

"Foo" gets typeset as expected, with the correct "German" quotation marks. But "Bar" gets typeset verbatim:

```
"`Bar"'
```

Apparently, the quotation marks "transformation" doesn't work inside `\newcommand`.

Since I never really understood what the more "magic" LaTeX commands (like `\relax`, `\detokenize` or `\makeatletter`) really were about, or how the underlying TeX really works, I'm stuck and cannot figure out **what I need to make the quotation marks inside the macro work properly**...

Comment: You can also use the macros `\glqq` and `\grqq`: `\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\glqq #1\grqq}`. `g` stands for German, `l` and `r`for left and right, `qq` for the double quotes; the same system is used to provide macros for single quotes (`\??q`) and the French Guillemets (`\f???`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution here is easier than in the "duplicate" question, because you *do* want quotation marks, instead of other effects of the `"` character.

For this you can use the alternate commands `\glqq` and `\grqq` defined by `babel[ngerman]` for the quotation marks.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Trivial case, the "real" macro is a *bit* more involved
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\glqq #1\grqq}

\begin{document}

"`Foo"'
\mymacro{Bar}

\end{document}
```