# How to parse a macro using babel replacements in a class file?

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing

I was trying to write a simple class and have the following issue:
I need to write some text containg German quotation marks that is staic and thus should be typeset by the class by default.

You can see in the MWE below that inside the `document` environment I can use 
 "` and `"'` to achieve the correct markings.
In the class file it does not work.
I can only use `\glqq` and `\grqq` to get ir right.

Is there a way to get it up correctly or is it simply impossible without the explicit macros in class files?

Here comes the `myclass.cls` file:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand{\abc}{"`abc"' \glqq abc \grqq}
```

And here comes the main tex file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
"`abc"' \glqq abc \grqq

\abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has already appeared: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/babel-shorthand-doesnt-work-in-macros

Comment: In a class you should use the non shorthand based form; and, in my opinion, no class should load `babel`.

Comment: I agree, but this is some sort of form to be typeset that I just manually copied from a Word document. Thus it's clear that it has to be written in German. OK, I see what I would had to do to get it working. For now I used a repacement with the non-shorthand form. This works for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `babel` allows the option `KeepShorthandsActive`, so you could  say

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[KeepShorthandsActive,ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand{\abc}{"`abc"'}
```

but this opens the way to several problems, because packages loaded in the preamble will be affected by the active `"`.

You could use

```
\shorthandon{"}
\newcommand{\abc}{"`abc"'}
\shorthandoff{"}
```

as suggested in [babel shorthand "| doesn't work in macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/babel-shorthand-doesnt-work-in-macros) but you can exploit the fact of being in a class file and so of being able to use `@`-commands. The list of shorthands is found in `ngermanb.ldf`

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"a}{\textormath{\"{a}\allowhyphens}{\ddot a}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"o}{\textormath{\"{o}\allowhyphens}{\ddot o}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"u}{\textormath{\"{u}\allowhyphens}{\ddot u}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"A}{\textormath{\"{A}\allowhyphens}{\ddot A}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"O}{\textormath{\"{O}\allowhyphens}{\ddot O}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"U}{\textormath{\"{U}\allowhyphens}{\ddot U}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"e}{\textormath{\"{e}}{\ddot e}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"E}{\textormath{\"{E}}{\ddot E}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"i}{\textormath{\"{\i}}%
                              {\ddot\imath}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"I}{\textormath{\"{I}}{\ddot I}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"s}{\textormath{\ss}{\@SS{}}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"S}{\SS}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"z}{\textormath{\ss}{\@SS{}}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"Z}{SZ}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"`}{\glqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"'}{\grqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"<}{\flqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{">}{\frqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"-}{\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"|}{%
  \textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
              \allowhyphens}{}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"=}{\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip}
```

so, for instance, instead of `"a` in a class macro, you can say `\"{a}\allowhyphens` and, instead of `"-` you can use

```
\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens
```

Note that the `\textormath` alternative is useless in a class macro wanting to use `"a`.

Probably `babel` should use an indirect method (there are much less memory problems nowadays). In my opinion it should say

```
\def\bbl@ngerman@quotehyphen{\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens}
```

and then

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"-}{\bbl@ngerman@quotehyphen}
```

For `"a` it should have

```
\def\bbl@ngerman@quotea@text{\"{a}\allowhyphens}
\def\bbl@ngerman@quotea@math{\ddot a}
```

and

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"a}{%
  \textormath{\bbl@ngerman@quotea@text}{\bbl@ngerman@quotea@math}%
}
```

This would allow class writers to access more easily and clearly the nonshorthand version.

Comment: Actually, `KeepShorthandsActive` has been there for ages.